# Tangent bundle as vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

To construct $\pi:TM \to M$ as vector bundle,

we need to find a local function $\Phi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb{R}^k$ as local trivilazation of $TM$ on $U$

We define this function $\Phi$ as follows on a smooth chart $(U,(x^i))$:

$$\Phi(v^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}|_p) = (p,(v^1,...,v^n))$$

The question is how to prove it's linear on fibers.

I know by definition it's sufficient to check $\Phi(V_p +W_p) = \Phi(V_p)+ \Phi(W_p)$ where $V_p \in T_pM$ with expression $V_p = v^i\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}|_p$

To do this
$$\Phi((v^i+w^i)\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}|_p) =(p,(v^1+w^1,...,v^n+w^n)) \ne (2p,(v^1+w^1,...,v^n+w^n)) = \Phi(V_p)+ \Phi(W_p)$$

What's wrong with my proof, since no addition on $U\subset M$ so this is not well defined.I don't know how to show it's linear on fiber since the codomain of $\Phi$ is not a vector space,only part of it is vector space.

Comment: what do you mean by $V_p + W_p$ what are $V_p$ and $W_p$ and $+$ is the minkowski sum?

Since you want to prove it is linear on the fibres what you want to prove is:

$\Psi(v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} |_p + \lambda v^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} |_p ) = \Psi(v^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} |_p) + \lambda \Psi( v^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} |_p)$

Comment: I am just going to answer by asking where is $p \in M$? Is this on the fibres $\pi^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: $p\in M$ is on the manifold. There is no canonical way to define an addition here. I mean what is Soutphole plus Nortphole?
The addition is purely defined on the tangential space because that has some vectorspace structure.

Comment: I got it thank you

Comment: That was a rhetorical question, but I m glad you realized what was wrong with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have such a thing as $2p$ for $p\in M$.
The vector space structure of the trivial bundle $U\times\Bbb R^n$ is of course defined *fibrewise*:
$$(p,v)+(p,w):=(p,v+w)$$